# Ubuntu: An init script that requires mysql

Tags: ubuntu, init

We have built some software that connects to MySQL and should be started on an Ubuntu server at boot.

What we're missing is how to ensure it starts at boot after MySQL.

Our init script includes the following at the top:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ourservice
# Required-Start:    $mysql $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Start/stop Our Service
### END INIT INFO
```

And on boot, ourservice was not running but MySQL was. So what am I missing?

To be clear, I have used update-rc.d ourservice defaults to install the script.